# how to plot timeseries events in a barcode style

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, zoo

How to plot a time series of events in a barcode style like the following hand made example?

[image: barcode style time series plot]

For the test the following zoo series can be used:

```
Tdate = c("2020-04-20", "2020-04-22","2020-05-16","2020-05-29", "2020-06-20", "2020-07-02", "2020-07-18", "2020-07-19", "2020-07-22", "2020-09-14", "2020-10-10", "2020-10-15", "2020-11-22", "2020-12-22", "2020-12-24", "2020-12-25")
Tevents = data.frame(station1=c(1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1),station2=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1), station3=c(0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0) )
Zevents<-zoo(Tevents,as.Date(Tdate))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could :

- `pivot_longer` the data according to `station`
- draw vertical lines with `geom_vline`
- use `facet_wrap` to get a plot per `station`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Tevents$dat <- as.Date(Tdate)


data <- Tevents %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains('station'), names_to = 'station')

ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(x = dat, y = 2))+
               geom_vline(aes(xintercept  = dat), data = filter(data,value == 1)) +
               coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1))+
               facet_wrap(~station, ncol = 1, strip.position = 'left') +
               theme(axis.title.y       = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.y        = element_blank(),
                     axis.ticks.y       = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
```

[image]